# get subchild value for a specific child in xml via jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, parent-child

I'am a newbie in jquery and I want to parse subchilds in a xml file for a specific child attribute, for example, I have this cities and districts list

```
<city name="ANKARA"> 
  <distr>BEYPAZARI</distr>
  <distr>GÜDÜL</distr>
  <distr>KAZAN</distr>
  <distr>ÇANKAYA</distr>
</city>
<city name="İSTANBUL">
 <distr>EMİNÖNÜ</distr>
 <distr>ÇATALCA</distr>
 <distr>BEYOĞLU</distr>
 <distr>BEYKOZ</distr>
 <distr>BEŞİKTAŞ</distr>
</city>
```

I use this code to get city list

```
 $(xml).find('city').each(function(){
     var city = $(this).attr("name");
     $("<option>").text(city).appendTo("#cityList");
 });
```

but I don't how to get the district list of for example Ankara,
someone could help me please
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(xml).find('city[name="ANKARA"]').each(function(){
     var city = $(this).attr("name");
     $("<option>").text(city).appendTo("#cityList");
 });
```

That's the "[attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)" selector you want.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked but now I created a change event for a select input and assigned the selected city to a variable name selectedCity and I wrote $(xml).find('city[name="'+selectedCity+'"]').each(function()... and it didn't work, is it normal?

Comment: Oops I forgot to the assign :selected value of the select input, now it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this to iterate through all the city and the child districts

```
$(xml).find('city').each(function(){
     var city = $(this).attr("name");
     $('distr', this).each(function(){
       //Add your code here to deal with Districts
    }
   });
   $("<option>").text(city).appendTo("#cityList");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

both answers above helped me to get exactly what I want,

```
$(xml).find('city[name="ANKARA"]').find('distr').each(function(){
    var distr = $(this).text();
    $("<option>").text(distr).appendTo("#district_list");
});
```

thanks a lot